# Condiciones dentro de objetos: Java

Tags: java, poo, objeto, bluej

Tengo el siguiente Contador y este es mi código de muestra:

```
public class ContadorLimiteRegreso {
    private int valorActual;
    private int limite;
    private int incr;

    public ContadorLimiteRegreso(int lim) {
        valorActual = 0;
        limite = lim;
        incr = 1;
    }

    public int obtActual() {
        if (valorActual == 0 && incr == -1) {
            incr = 1;
        } else { 
            if (valorActual == limite && incr == 1) {
                incr = -1;
            }
        }

        int ret = valorActual;
        valorActual += incr;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Se me ha pedido crear un ejecutador que cree una instancia de la clase con un límite de 2 y sin utilizar ciclos. Así mismo tengo que invocar e imprimir el resultado de dicha invocación 7 veces para que la salida sea:

```
0
1
2
1
0
1
2
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y coloca el código que tengas hecho para poder ayudarte a resolver tus dudas.

Comment: He hecho los cambios debidos para la coherencia del mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que, si es que entiendo bien su pregunta, debemos de recurrir a la **recursividad**, es decir, llamar una función dentro de sí misma. Con esa técnica logramos "iterar" **sin necesidad de una estructura de control cíclica** como "*for, while, etc*".

Esta sería mi solución para esa cuestión:

```
public class MyClass {

private int limite; // El número max al que llegará
private int iteraciones; // Cantidad de iteraciones

public MyClass(int lim, int itera) {
    limite = lim;
    iteraciones = itera;
}

int acumulador = 0;
public int getActual() {

    if(acumulador >= 0) {

        System.out.println(acumulador);
        acumulador++;

        if(acumulador == (limite + 1)) {
            acumulador = limite * -1;
        }

    } else {

        limite--;
        System.out.println(limite);

        if(limite == 0) {
            limite = acumulador * -1;
            acumulador = 1;
        }
    }

    iteraciones--;

    return iteraciones;
}

public int getResult() { // Función recursiva

    int iteracion_actual = getActual();

    if(iteracion_actual > 0) {

        return getResult();

    } else {
        return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Luego instanciamos la clase(MyClass) e invocamos al método **getResult()**(el ejecutador del proceso):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo desea puede añadir un try/catch para el manejo de errores.

Resultado:

[image: imagen-resultado]

Answer (score 0):

*Bueno quizá no sea muy optimo lo que te planteo, pero lo hice para que veas como se puede hacer dichos procesos sin usar ciclos de repetición, ya es cuestión de que pulas el código y lo dejes como mas te guste.
He creado 1 método y 2 funciones,* **ejecutor()**, **llenarArreglo()** e **imprimirDatos()** *Aunque el ejecutor lo puedes reemplazar por el constructor, de igual manera va a funcionar. Dejo el código para que lo ejecutes y lo analices.*

```js
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContadorLimiteRegreso {

    private int contador = 0;
    private int cantidadDatosArreglo;
    private int cantidadImprimir;
    private boolean bandera = false;

    public void ejecutarProceso() {
        this.cantidadDatosArreglo = 3;
        this.cantidadImprimir = 7;
        List<Integer> datos = llenarArreglo(new ArrayList<>());
        this.contador = 0;
        imprimirDatos(datos);
    }

    private List<Integer> llenarArreglo(List<Integer> datos) {
        if (datos.size() < this.cantidadImprimir) {

            if (contador == this.cantidadDatosArreglo - 1 || bandera) {
                bandera = true;
                if (contador == 2) {
                    datos.add(contador);                    
                }
                contador--;
                if (contador == 0) {
                    bandera = false;
                }
                if (datos.size() < this.cantidadImprimir) {
                    datos.add(contador);                    
                }
            } else {
                bandera = false;
                if (datos.size() > 0 && contador == 0) {
                    contador++; 
                }
                datos.add(contador);
                contador++;
            }
            return llenarArreglo(datos);
        }

        return datos;
    }

    private List<Integer> imprimirDatos(List<Integer> datos) {
        if (this.cantidadImprimir > 0) {
            System.out.println(datos.get(contador));
            contador++;
            this.cantidadImprimir--;
            return imprimirDatos(datos);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

*Y en tu main lo ejecutas de la siguiente manera:*

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    // vender();
    System.out.println("Iniciar Proceso");
    new ContadorLimiteRegreso().ejecutarProceso();
    System.out.println("Finalizar Proceso");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

*Puedes dejar el main sin el bloque* **try/catch** *No recuerdo como se le llama a ese proceso donde la function se llama a si misma hasta cumplir la sentencia generando así un ciclo de repetición, si lo averiguas, puedes hacerlo saber.*

Comment: eso es una funcion recursiva.. y si no le dejan usar iteraciones, dudo mucho que le dejen usar funciones recursivas. Mas alla de eso, creo que OP simplemente necesita crear un objeto en el main, y luego llamar 7 veces a obtActual